# bootstrap panels not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-accordion

I've got a bootstrap accordion panel, and the panels aren't collapsing like they should when I click on them if they're already open. I can't figure out why. I had this working with the panels hard coded, but once I set up wp_query to load the panels, everything worked except the panels closing.

the function:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).find('.collapse.in').prev('.panel-heading');
        if(offset) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(offset).offset().top -50
            }, 500); 
        }
    }); 
});

$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});

</script>
```

and the nested loops to generate the accordion panels:

```
<div class="home-contents">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">   
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1 class="faqheading"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
           <!--  <div class="col-sm-9" style="float: none; margin: auto;"><?php the_content(); ?></div> -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container -->

    <div class="blog-page">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

                    <?php
                    /*
                     * Loop through Categories and Display Posts within
                     */
                    $post_type = 'faq';
                    // Get all the taxonomies for this post type
                    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) ); /* gets taxonomy from posts */
                    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
                      // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
                      $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
                      foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

                        <div class="groupheading col-sm-3"><h5 style=" color: #3fa9f5; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 300;"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h5></div>

                            <?php
                            $args = array(
                              'post_type' => $post_type,
                              'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts

                              'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                  'field' => 'slug',
                                  'terms' => $term->slug,
                                  'orderby' => 'collapse id',
                                  'order' => 'desc'
                                )
                              ),
                              'order' => 'DESC'
                            );
                            ?>

                        <?php           
                        $posts = new WP_Query($args);
                        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

                          <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-9">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo 'collapse'.get_the_id();?>"><?php $value = get_field( "faq_heading"); echo $value; ?></a>
                              </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="<?php echo 'collapse'.get_the_id();?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                              <div class="panel-body col-sm-9">
                                <p><?php $value = get_field( "faq_text", false, false); echo $value; ?></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div> <!-- .panel -->
                        <?php endwhile;?>

                    <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-9 mobilehide" style="height: 45px;"></div>
                    <div class="groupheading col-sm-3 mobilehide" style="height: 45px;"></div>

                        <?php
                         endif; ?>

                      <?php endforeach;
                    endforeach; ?>
                    </div> <!-- .panel-group -->
                  </div><!-- end col-sm-12 -->
                </div> <!-- end row -->
              </div><!-- end container -->
            </div><!-- end blog-page -->
          </div> <!-- .container -->
```

Edit: Ok, I've added the following but it's still not working:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.cf").click(function(){
        $(this).parentsUntil(".panel-default").find(.children(".panel-collapse")).removeClass("in");
    });f
});
</script>
```

2nd edit: I feel like the issue is that .parent isn't finding the right element, but I'm not sure how to direct it correctly.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.cf").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("collapsed");
        $(this).parent().find(".panel-collapse .collapse").removeClass(".panel-collapse .collapse").addClass(".panel-collapse .collapse .in");
        $(this).find().parent('.collapse.in').removeClass(".panel-collapse.collapse").addClass(".panel-collapse.collapse.in");;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've compared every line of the code to the working page with the hard coded panels, and the only difference is that the "collapsed" and "in" classes are appearing as they should on the hard coded page, but not on the new page. I just can't find any reason for this.

Comment: And for some clarification, the panels will collapse if I click on a different panel. Just not if I click on the open panel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved this. I had originally built this page as part of a wordpress site, and I had included the bootstrap code at the top of the template. In the process of rebuilding the whole site, I put a new bootstrap include in the header file for the site. I left the old include at the top of my template when I got around to working on this particular page, and this redundancy of code was, somehow, causing the collapse to function incorrectly. I still don't know/understand why this was the case, but I've got it working correctly now.

I realize I didn't actually get any responses to this, but thank you to everyone who at least looked.